# Python: Convert dataframe column from Series to Datetime datatype

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe table shown below:

```
Day_Part    Start_Time    End_Time
Quarter 1   2014, 1, 1    2015, 3, 1
Quarter 2   2014, 3, 3    2014, 7, 3
```

The columns "Start_Time" and "End_Time" are pandas Series.  I want to convert the datatype of both columns to datetime instead.

I need those two columns to have datetime datatypes because in a later block of code, I say if this column is between this date and this date then I label it Quarter 1.

*Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Um, I'm fairly certain that the datatype is not series. How do you figure they are? Why don't you post the output of `df.head()` and `df.dtypes`. I suspect your columns have `object` dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to_datetime() with a format string to extract the date:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df.Start_Time, format='%Y, %m, %d').dt.date
```

You can also modify the dates in place:

```
df[['Start_Time', 'End_Time']] = df[['Start_Time', 'End_Time']].apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y, %m, %d').dt.date)
```

Or, you can convert to date when reading the csv:

```
to_date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y, %m, %d').date()
converters = dict(Start_Time=to_date, End_Time=to_date)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), converters=converters)
```

A testable example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = u"""
Day_Part,Start_Time,End_Time
"Quarter 1","2014, 1, 1","2015, 3, 1"
"Quarter 2","2014, 3, 3","2014, 7, 3"
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

# You can use `to_datetime()` with a format string to extract the date:
date = pd.to_datetime(df.Start_Time, format='%Y, %m, %d').dt.date

# The start month in the second row is 3
assert date[1].month == 3

# You can also modify in place
df[['Start_Time', 'End_Time']] = df[['Start_Time', 'End_Time']].apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y, %m, %d').dt.date)

# The end month in the second row is 7
assert df.End_Time[1].month == 7

# You can convert to date when reading the csv
to_date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y, %m, %d').date()
converters = dict(Start_Time=to_date, End_Time=to_date)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), converters=converters)

# The end month in the first row is 3
assert df.End_Time[0].month == 3
```